Convert units, get different results when fitting extreme value distribution with extRemes
I am using the fevd() and lr.test() functions to examine precipitation using the extRemes R package. My primary issue is that I get different results when I use inches vs millimeters for the input data. Secondary to that, sometimes I get warnings and I'm wondering if they indicate a different path is taken to optimize the parameters.
Here's an example showing how a multiplier gives different results. Also, if I set seed to 3, no warnings are produced. If set seed to 4, warnings are produced when I fit fevd() using the location.fun parameter.
library(extRemes)
set.seed(3)
dat <- data.frame(values = rnorm(30, mean = 3, sd = 1.5),
                  years = 1990:2019)
dat$values25 <- dat$values*25
dat

gev_fit <- fevd(x = values, data = dat, type = "GEV")
gev_fit25 <- fevd(x = values25, data = dat, type = "GEV")
gev_fit
gev_fit25

# Fit a non-stationary GEV distribution
gev_fit_loc <- fevd(x = values, data = dat, location.fun = ~ years, 
                    type = "GEV")
gev_fit_loc25 <- fevd(x = values25, data = dat, 
                      location.fun = ~ years, type = "GEV")
gev_fit_loc
gev_fit_loc25

lr.test(gev_fit, gev_fit_loc)
lr.test(gev_fit25, gev_fit_loc25)

This is my primary concern:
The first lr.test() gives a p-value of 0.7642 and the second reports a p-value of 1.0, even though the only difference is the input data in the second "25" example has been multiplied by 25.
Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I overlooking something obvious?
Second, if I run the above code but set seed to 4, I get this warning:
>In log(z) : NaNs produced

when fitting the non-stationary GEV, but only for "values" not "values25". Can anyone provide some insight on what this warning is indicating?

Something to look at. Try to get all the numbers to be around 1, to the extent that's possible. Instead of years 1991, 1992, 1993, subtract 1990 so you have 1, 2, 3. Instead of measuring rainfall in mm, try cm, dm, or even m (I don't know how much precipitation we're talking about). Rescaling theoretically makes no difference -- so you're free to do whatever's convenient -- but it can make a practical difference.

Have you looked at the magnitudes of intermediate results?  Most likely something is getting so small that binary roundoff(in floats) is causing issues.

From the manual page: "For non-stationary fitting it is recommended that the covariates within the generalized linear models are (at least approximately) centered and scaled." Scaling the years values with the defaults in scale() seems to remove the first problem.

@EdM Thank you so much! That took care of the issue and now the warning disappears too. I don't know how the warning was related to it, but I haven't been able to reproduce it since I switched to scale().
